# find the smallest value of the real number $x+2y+4z$.

Tags: inequality

*question*

If $x,y,z$ are real numbers such that $3x+y+2z \geq 3$ and $-x+2y+4z \geq 5$ find the smallest value of the real number $x+2y+4z$.

*my idea*

I forgot that we can't decrease to inequality so this is my non helpful idea:

[image]

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: ... as already mentioned in response to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4796834/42969

Comment: You got a right answer by a wrong way 

Comment: **Answer** : You *can* reduce the number of variables . Indeed, letting $y+2z=3t$, then we need to find the minimum of $\color{#c00}{M=x+6t}$ .

From $3x+3t≥3$, we get $x≥1-t$ , which implies $\color{#c00}{M≥1+5t}$ . Then, you get :

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}x+t≥1\\
-x+6t≥5\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &7t≥6\\
\implies &t≥\frac 67\\
\implies &M≥1+5\cdot \frac 67\\
&\quad=\frac {37}{7}\;\;\;\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My attempt**:

Let

1. $3x+y+2z=3+a$,
2. $-x+2y+4z=5+b$,

where $a\geq0,b\geq0$, so we can find:
\begin{gather}
\frac{4}{3}x + 2y+4z = \frac{16}{3} + \frac{2a}{3} + \frac{2b}{3}, \quad [(1)+(2)]\times \frac{2}{3}\\[.2cm]
x = \frac{1}{7} + \frac{2a}{7} - \frac{b}{7}, \quad [(1)\times 2-(2)]\times \frac{1}{7}
\end{gather}
Then the objective function can be expressed as
$$
x+2y+4z = \frac{16}{3} +\frac{2a}{3} + \frac{2b}{3} - \frac{x}{3} = \color{red}{\frac{37}{7} + \frac{4}{7}a + \frac{5}{7}b \geq \frac{37}{7}}
$$
So the smallest value of the objective function is $\frac{37}{7}$, the inequality is only true if $a=0$ and $b=0$.

- The general method to solve this kind of problem is to use [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).
- Fortunately, your question is simple enough that we don't need to use it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial point here is that in general, if you have a region $S$ delimited by two planes, the expression $x+2y+4z$ (or any non-zero linear combination of $x,y,z$) will range over the whole of $\Bbb R$ as $(x,y,z)$ ranges over $S$. In other words, there will be no smallest value.

The exception occurs when $x+2y+4z$ can be expressed as a linear combination
$$x+2y+4z=A(3x+y+2z) + B(-x+2y+4z)$$
from which it would follow that $x+2y+4z$ must be at least $3A+5B$.

So can you find $A$ and $B$ so that the above equation holds? You need $3A-B=1$ (from the coefficient of $x$), $A+2B=2$ (from the coefficient of $y$), and $2A+4B=4$ (from the coefficient of $z$). In general such $A$ and $B$ won't exist, but you know that they must exist if this question is to have a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}3x+y+2z\ge3\\-x+2y+4z\ge5\end {cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}6x+(2y+4z)\ge6\\-x+(2y+4z)\ge5\end {cases}\Rightarrow x\ge\frac17$$ therefore
$2y+4z\ge6-\dfrac67=\dfrac{36}{7}$ and $2y+4z\ge5+\dfrac17=\dfrac{36}{7}$
Thus $$x+2y+4z\ge\frac{37}{7}$$

Comment: Can we decrease to inequalities?

Comment: The conclusion $x \ge \frac 17$ is *wrong.* For example, $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 2)$ satisfies both inequalities. Note that you generally can not *subtract* inequalities from each other.